# Selenium loop through emails in Mailinator

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello Selenium (python) experts.
I have 2 emails in Mailinator where I am sending some email templates.
I am calling those emails as follow to make it easy to explain my problem:

- email1@mailinator.com
- email2@mailinator.com

I am sending the exact same content to both email, and I am trying to target the email with selenium and open it.

Right now with selenium I am using the XPATH to target the email, but I realised that this XPATH is a dynamic link, which mean for each email I send, Mailinator generate a random number that attach to the email XPATH. for example:

```
email1 = //*[@id="row_email1-1626692999-529929"]/td[2]
email2 = //*[@id="row_email2-1628652999-526029"]/td[2]
```

I was wondering if there is an option to loop through the body of Mailinator and target all the email that contained the XPATH `email1` or `email2` and open them.

I am new to selenium, so please if something is not clear or need more infos, just let me know

Thank you so much guys

EDIT:
this is the web driver configuration to run the browser in full screen mode but it start in small size

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://mailinator.com')
```

Comment: I tried to understand, but still not sure I got it. You are sending email with some content (I guess String) to 2 email addresses in Mailinator. Not you want to open one of those 2 emails and find if that email was received? Since I see no way to see emails in several inboxes in the same time. You can enter particular email inbox and then search for email with known content inside. It that the case? If so - what is the question?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to loop through emails in the mailinator web interface? Or through the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OR` in xpath like below  :

```
//*[@id='row_email1-1626692999-529929' or @id='row_email2-1628652999-526029']/td[2]
```

or a way better approach would be to use `find_elements`

for that, I am assuming the below xpath  :

```
//*[contains(@id,'row_email')]/td[2]
```

would represent all the emails link.

**Sample code  :**

```
for emails in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id,'row_email)']/td[2]")
    emails.click() or whatever you wanna do here with single mail link
```

Comment: Hello mate, thank you for your time and reply. So I tried with the `for` but it seems that python/selenium ignores that statement and jump directly to the next line of code throwing an error stating `element not intractable`

Comment: So I changed from `find_elements` to `find_element` as I have only one email in this inbox. but I get the error `unable to locate element` make me think that is the same issue you helped me to solve earlier with the iframe

Comment: What is the view port for this web element ? Make sure to launch browser in full screen mode.

Comment: this is the view port I have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">` I am trying to launch the browser in full screen but it appears just half screen. I will update my post with the web driver config

Comment: Can you add `driver.maximize_window()` this line to maximize the windows size

Comment: the maximise window worked perfectly. I will test the loop later again. Thank you very much for your help, you are my hero